# Why does changing pen size not work here?

Tags: c#, graphics

So this is my code:

```
float penSize = 1;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, penSize);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p , new Point(0 , 0) , new Point(100, 100));
        penSize = 5;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, 0), new Point(50, 150));
        penSize = 10;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, 0), new Point(30, 200));
        p.Dispose();
```

This is inside my Panel Paint event. 
I would assume that this would output 3 lines, all of the varying thicknesses (1,5 and 10).

However it simply outputs this:
[image: All lines of same thickness?]

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Pen instance for each size. The Pen instance doesn't keep a reference to your float, so changing your `penSize` will not affect the already created `Pen` instance. That is by design, floats are value types, their values are copied, not referenced.

```
using( Pen p1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 1))
{
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p1 , new Point(0 , 0) , new Point(100, 100));
}
using(Pen p5 = new Pen(Color.Black, 5))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p5, new Point(0, 0), new Point(50, 150));
}
using(Pen p10 = new Pen(Color.Black, 10))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p10, new Point(0, 0), new Point(30, 200));
}
```

As an alternative you can set the `Width` property of a single Pen instance, as suggested by [kennyxyz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815938/kennyzx) in the comments:

```
// start with a Width of 1 
using( Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1))
{
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen , new Point(0 , 0) , new Point(100, 100));
  pen.Width = 5;
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(50, 150));
  pen.Width = 10;
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(30, 200));
}  // Dispose is called here
```

Your result:

[image: drawing]

Comment: Or just set the Width property of the Pen instance, this way, don't need to create a pen instance for each size.